# How to Add a controller service using Nipyapi?

Tags: python, rest, automation, apache-nifi, nipyapi

I am automating a NiFi workflow, where I am using DetectDuplicate processor. How can I add DistributedMapCacheClientService controller service by using list_all_controller_types() or any other method